Testing in-app purchases with sandbox mode automatically closing bottom-sheet after signing in and reopening
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase_storekit/store_kit_wrappers.dart';
import 'package:weight_loss_app/modules/talking_oath/talking_outh/binding/talking_oath_binding.dart';
import 'package:weight_loss_app/modules/talking_oath/talking_outh/view/talking_oath_page.dart';

class InAppPurchaseUtils extends GetxController {
  // Singleton instance
  InAppPurchaseUtils._();
  static final InAppPurchaseUtils _instance = InAppPurchaseUtils._();
  static InAppPurchaseUtils get instance => _instance;

  late StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>> _purchasesSubscription;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    _purchasesSubscription.cancel();
    super.onClose();
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    if (await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable()) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdates();
    }
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdates() {
    _purchasesSubscription = InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream.listen(
      (List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
        _handlePurchaseUpdates(purchaseDetailsList);
      },
      onDone: () => _purchasesSubscription.cancel(),
      onError: (error) {
        log('Purchase stream error: $error');
      },
    );
  }

  void _handlePurchaseUpdates(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    log('In-App Purchase Listener Called');
    for (var purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
      log('Purchase details status: ${purchaseDetails.status}');
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
        log('Pending purchase: ${purchaseDetails.status}');
        // Show pending UI if needed
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
        log('Error during purchase: ${purchaseDetails.error}');
        // Handle error
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.canceled) {
        log('Purchase canceled');
        // Handle canceled purchase
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
          purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
        log('Product purchased or restored');
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        }
        _navigateToNextScreen();
        // Handle purchased or restored product
      }
    }
  }

  void _navigateToNextScreen() {
    Get.to(() => const TalkingOathPage(), binding: TalkingOathBinding());
  }

  Future<void> buyConsumableProduct(String productId) async {
    try {
      final transactions = await SKPaymentQueueWrapper().transactions();
      for (var transaction in transactions) {
        await SKPaymentQueueWrapper().finishTransaction(transaction);
      }

      final Set<String> productIds = {productId};
      final ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse =
          await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(productIds);

      if (productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty) {
        log('Product not found');
        return;
      }

      final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
        productDetails: productDetailResponse.productDetails.first,
      );

      await InAppPurchase.instance.buyConsumable(
        purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
        autoConsume: true,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      log('Failed to buy product: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> restorePurchases() async {
    try {
      await InAppPurchase.instance.restorePurchases();
    } catch (error) {
      log('Failed to restore purchases: $error');
    }
  }
}

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.0, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-PK)
• Flutter version 3.22.0 on channel stable at /Users/muhammadfarooqiqbal/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 5dcb86f68f (12 days ago), 2024-05-09 07:39:20 -0500
• Engine revision f6344b75dc
• Dart version 3.4.0
• DevTools version 2.34.3
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/muhammadfarooqiqbal/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 33.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15F31d
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.88.0
